# Is it possible to load an external shared object file from the Download directory in Android?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Is it possible to load an external shared object file from a unusual path, e.g. the Download directory, in Android system?
Because I read the [System.loadLibrary](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)) and the [System.load](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System#load(java.lang.String)) methods and I don't understand if it is possible.

Furthermore, I also tried to implement something similar, i.e. put a `libhello.so` in the Download directory of an emulator and call `System.load("/storage/emulated/0/Download/libhello.so")`, but I got the error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/storage/emulated/0/Download/libhello.so" not found`.

So I was wondering if it was ok or not.

Comment: On newer Android devices you can access the downloaded items only using Android scoped storage Java API, therefore loading it via `System.load` or any other way that bases on `dlopen` will not work.

Comment: You sent us to the documentation and there you can read: `public static void loadLibrary (String libname)

Loads the native library specified by the libname argument. The libname argument must not contain any platform specific prefix, file extension or path.` .So you know that it is not possible as you use a full path.

Comment: Hmmm... But... The other one should work: `public static void load (String filename)

Loads the native library specified by the filename argument. The filename argument must be an absolute path name.`. Well on Android devices below Android Q i think. On newer devices your app has no access to files which are not created by the app itself. Use File.exists() and File.canRead() to check if your app has read access before you try to load the lib.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It turns out that I missed `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);` in the activity class because I thought that only the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the Manifest was enough.